# What is the execution time of an if statement?

Tags: c#, time-complexity

What is the T(n) of if statement  in this code

```
 public static int min(int[] v)
        {
            int x = v[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
            {
                if (x >v[i])
                    x = v[i];
            }
            return x;
        }
```

I think the if  itself will be executed n times but our teacher said n^2 I dont understand why ?

Comment: No, this will run in `O(n)` time. If statements are neglected when you do a time complexity analysis.

Comment: the complexity of looking up an array element by index depends on the compiler implementation, but no real world compiler would use a loop internally to access an array element. therefore the time complexity of the evaluation of the conditional expression inside the if statement cannot be n^2.

Comment: @mahmoud I think they are talking about the evaluation of the conditional expression, not the branching/jump.

Comment: Unless, `y` is not an `array`. If `y` some kind of `Data structure` which loop through all elements to get the element at specific index then it will run in `N^2`

Comment: Yes @dlatikay. That's why I said they are not counted.

Comment: public static int min(int[] v)
        {
            int x = v[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
            {
                if (x >v[i])
                    x = v[i];
            }
            return x;
        }
Here guys in this code to get the minimum value in an array  its O(n) not O(n^2) right ?

Comment: Yes, it's O(n), there is only ever one enumeration of this array that happens.

Comment: Go teach the teacher a lesson.  Fix your code first, you want to start at [1] since you already got [0].   And fret a bit about v.Length == 0.

Comment: @HansPassant yes its better to start i from 1 but still it works this way and I just copied the code where my classmate posted didnt analyze it  I was more focused in  execution time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O(1).

The `if` by itself executes in constant time. Condition inside `if` may have any time complexity so you need to pay attention to it to.

Updated version of sample shows `int[] v` as data for sequence which means access to `i`th element is O(1) and total time of `min` is O(n) as expected from standard implementation of that method.

Note that without knowing what data structures used in the code it is not possible to provide correct estimate. One could guess that `y` in the original sample code is standard array, but it may not be the case for algorithm you are using. For example if you use linked list as data storage for indexed structure (i.e. you've implemented `IList<...>` as linked list of nodes) than access to `i`th element would be O(n) even if normally x[i] would be O(1) for arrays.

Comment: that's what I was thinking , I think they got it wrong because at the loop 
the condition is asked n+1 times because it is a loop but  normally if not inside a loop it should be  a constant, also she said that if statement always is n+1  so she must have taken it wrong from the loop , thanks for the answer